# Does .NET Web Service/WCF Supports file transfer between SFTP Servers?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I want to create a service in .NET to transfer files between SFTP servers.

What will be the best way to choose as I know WCF doesn't support SFTP, does SFTP is supported by .NET Core.

Thanks & Regards
Supratik De

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experience with Renci.SshNet (https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET, or as NuGet package). I used it in some projects transferring files between Windows and Linux.

I did not use it with .NET Core, but it should be supported.

For a first start, you can try:

```
...
using System.IO;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;
...

...
var sftpClient = new SftpClient(host, user, password);
sftpClient.Connect();


// download
using (FileStream localStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    sftpClient.DownloadFile(hostPath, localStream);
}

// upload
using (FileStream localStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    sftpClient.UploadFile(localStream, hostPath);
}
...
```